# NumPy's implementation of free-function-reshape() vs member-function-reshape()?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like some clarification about how NumPy's free-function, reshape(), is implemented as opposed to how nd-array's member-function reshape() is implemented.

**For example:**

```py
a = np.reshape(np.array([1,2,3]),[3,1])
```

versus

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a.reshape([3,1])
```

I do understand they are 'different', as one is a class method and the other a function, but my question is more about how are they scripted/implemented.

Does the member-method call the free-function?

**Like this:**

```py
import reshape

class array:

     def __init__(self,my_array):
         self.my_array = my_array

     def reshape(self):
          self.my_array = reshape(self.my_array)
```

Or is something else going on? Is this how the class method of the NumPy array class would be coded? Does it import and use a function within a method, or is the same code copied in both function definitions? You know what I'm saying...

Comment: In most cases, the function version delegates the action to the object's method.  If the object isn't already an array it will create one.  For `reshape` the delegation is a cryptic `_wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)`.  If you try to look up method code it says 'builtin' (i.e. compiled).

Comment: Yea, that's the other interesting thing about numpy, most of the core features are programmed in C.

Comment: @hpaulj , Just say we presumed that these functions were  written entirely in python, without wrapping to a compiled code, how would the a.reshape and reshape(a) functions be coded?

Comment: @AlecDay if you post a separate question, I will answer that too.  I think it's better for the historical record if good questions are categorized into separate threads.

Answer (score 2):

### What we already know:

In this statement:

```
a = np.reshape(np.array([1,2,3]),[3,1])
```

reshape() is a free function with this [signature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).  array() is also a free function and array constructor with this [signature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

However, in these statements:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3]) 
a.reshape([3,1])
```

array() is still a free function and constructor, but reshape() is a member function (method) of the nd-array class/object.  Unlike the free function reshape(), [the member function, reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape), allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments. For example, a.reshape(10, 11) is equivalent to a.reshape((10, 11)).

### **Answering the question:**

The actual implementation of these is a little harder to understand because the core features of numpy are implemented in C.  Like @hpaulj said, the reshape() delegation is a cryptic call to compiled code.

I suspect the reshape code looks more like [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c), [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c), or [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c):

```
static PyObject *
array_reshape(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    static char *keywords[] = {"order", NULL};
    PyArray_Dims newshape;
    PyObject *ret;
    NPY_ORDER order = NPY_CORDER;
    Py_ssize_t n = PyTuple_Size(args);

    if (!NpyArg_ParseKeywords(kwds, "|O&", keywords,
                PyArray_OrderConverter, &order)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (n <= 1) {
        if (n != 0 && PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0) == Py_None) {
            return PyArray_View(self, NULL, NULL);
        }
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O&:reshape", PyArray_IntpConverter,
                              &newshape)) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!PyArray_IntpConverter(args, &newshape)) {
            if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                                "invalid shape");
            }
            goto fail;
        }
    }
    ret = PyArray_Newshape(self, &newshape, order);
    npy_free_cache_dim_obj(newshape);
    return ret;

 fail:
    npy_free_cache_dim_obj(newshape);
    return NULL;
}
```

as opposed to this:

```
import reshape

class array:

     def __init__(self,my_array):
         self.my_array = my_array

     def reshape(self):
          self.my_array = reshape(self.my_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [61]: def myreshape(obj, shape): 
    ...:     return np.asarray(obj).reshape(shape) 
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [62]: myreshape(np.arange(12),(3,4))                                                                      
Out[62]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [63]: myreshape(list(range(12)),(3,4))                                                                    
Out[63]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

where `np.asarray` is:

```
np.array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

that is it returns `a` itself if possible, otherwise it makes an array.

Another way to code this to test if `obj` has the `reshape` attribute:

```
In [67]: def myreshape(obj, shape): 
    ...:     if not hasattr(obj,'reshape'): 
    ...:         obj = np.array(obj) 
    ...:     return obj.reshape(shape)
```

I've ignored `order`.  And haven't tested it for behavior with subclasses like 
`np.matrix` and `np.ma`.